# Materialize Icons, why is arrow_right taking up more space than arrow_left

Tags: html, css, materialize

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">     
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col s12">
   <a class="btn right light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="addDataBtn"><i class="material-icons">arrow_forwards</i></a>
   <a class="btn left light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="addDataBtn"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
</div>
```

[image]

```
<div class="col s12">
   <a class="btn right light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="addDataBtn"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
   <a class="btn left light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="addDataBtn"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see, from the above code snippets. For some reason the fowards_arrow and back_arrow icons take up different amounts of space. Is this an oversight?
How can I make them symmetrical?

Edit: Added materialize stylesheet so others can replicate the code

Comment: Tried it, no issues here https://jsfiddle.net/oykd9jpL/ Add your used css to the question. I think your problem is with class right

Comment: Hey bro, have updated the code to include the materialize stylesheet.
https://jsfiddle.net/sqv5gfzr/

Comment: Hi, change arrow_forwards to arrow_forward, thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the s from arrow_forwards

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">     
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <div class="col s12">
       <a class="btn right light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="addDataBtn"><i class="material-icons">arrow_forward</i></a>
       <a class="btn left light-blue lighten-3 black-text" id="addDataBtn"><i class="material-icons">arrow_back</i></a>
    </div>
```